# Surge Command Not Found

Tags: shell, command-line, surge.sh

I have read through a lot of posts regarding `command not found` error messages in the terminal but I can't find any specific to `surge`.

I am running into an error when using the `surge` command in my terminal. I ran `npm install --global surge` in my terminal and everything looks okay, but when I run the command `surge` it returns `command not found`.

The other `npm` packages on my computer work fine. I tested `create-react-app` and no errors. I am somewhat new to this, any advice would be appreciated!!

Thanks and cheers!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a chance that the `surge` binary is missing from your terminal's current `PATH`. To check if that is the case, locate where is the binary installed by default (in my machine is found under `/usr/local/bin` directory) and check if that directory is present in your `PATH`, by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

In case it is not, you can add it by running:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/surge/location
```

Then check if it works now:

```
surge
```

If that's the case, to make this change persitent across reboots, you can `echo` the current `PATH` you have defined:

```
echo $PATH
```

And then export the result of that last command to your `~/.bashrc` file, by adding this line:

```
export PATH=/previous/command/output/here
```

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:\`which surge\` && source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 9):

Just use npx surge instead of surge
:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `surge` executable is installed?

what shell are you in?

If in `bash`, try re-`hash`-ing:

```
       hash [-lr] [-p filename] [-dt] [name]
              Each time hash is invoked, the full pathname of the command name is determined by searching the directories in $PATH  and  remembered.
              Any  previously-remembered  pathname is discarded.  If the -p option is supplied, no path search is performed, and filename is used as
              the full filename of the command.  The -r option causes the shell to forget all remembered locations.  The -d option causes the  shell
              to  forget  the  remembered  location of each name.  If the -t option is supplied, the full pathname to which each name corresponds is
              printed.  If multiple name arguments are supplied with -t, the name is printed before the hashed full pathname.  The -l option  causes
              output  to  be  displayed  in a format that may be reused as input.  If no arguments are given, or if only -l is supplied, information
              about remembered commands is printed.  The return status is true unless a name is not found or an invalid option is supplied.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am sorry for sounding like such a novice, but can you elaborate on your first question. To install I followed the instructions surge.sh, but I did receive this warning when installing - [npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142]